# Is there any way we can disprove the law of conservation of energy

Tags: energy-conservation

is there any way to explain this.
In experiments

Comment: If you built a perpetual motion machine, that would do it.

Comment: It's essentially conservation of energy and *mass*

Comment: https://youtu.be/cnGYMe6GBeQ

Comment: I think it is reasonable to ask what experiments might in theory invalidate the law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good proof would be a demonstration that the laws of nature exhibit time dependence- for example, that special relativity is false on thursday afternoons, or that E = mc^2 was actually E = mc^1.9999 last month.